# Can't Print Script in Script Workspace

Tags: filemaker

I have a Filemaker project [FM 16 Pro Advanced] with multiple databases running under Windows 10 build 1803.  For all of the databases, save one, I can print a script from the Script Workspace with either Crtl-P or selecting Print from the drop-down File menu.

For the one problem database, I have tried "Recover..." with the FM Recover tool, but it made no difference.

Does anyone have ideas about what would cause this behavior and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Print option greyed out? If so you probably have a restriction on printing with the current privilege set that your user account uses. Try logging in with full access and check the privileges.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not grayed-out, it doesn't show at all.  The problem seems to be related only to join tables, though it is inconsistent, save for this single join table which is consistent in not displaying the print dialog.

Comment: Is the join table from a table in a separate file? If so, have you tried logging in to this file with full access privileges and print from there?